# use python socket to build a ftp server

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

#### I want to use python socket to build a FTP server.

but the client did not recognize the server sent a FTP package.

this is the situation when I visit a my FTP server

[image]

client still thinks I sent a TCP package

this is the situation when I visit a formal FTP server

[image]

So when I want client to enter passive mode, the client still thinks it is a tcp contend.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('192.168.233.129', 31503))
s.listen(5) 
print 'Waiting for connection...'

clientSock, addr = s.accept()
print 'Accept new connection from %s:%s...' % addr

clientSock.send('220-\r\n220 end\r\n'.encode('utf-8')) 
 print clientSock.recv(65536)
 clientSock.send('331 password\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
 print clientSock.recv(65536)
 clientSock.send('230 login\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
 print clientSock.recv(65536)
 clientSock.send('215 UnixType\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
print clientSock.recv(65536)
clientSock.send('227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,233,129,105,160).\r\n')
```

Is there any way to make client to recognize my package as a FTP package?

EDIT:Formatting changes

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: this is my test code.

Comment: So 31503 is FTP port ?

Comment: I find it correct, I should use 21 port......thank you

Comment: @Eureka: you can use a non-standard port for FTP but then you have to tell Wireshark which protocol you have on this port (something like "Decode As ..." in the menus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the port number you are using , you should use 21 as port number. Then client can detect it as FTP

If you are using other than 21 , in wireshark you have to decode port number as 21(Wireshark --> Analyze --> Decode as --> Give your port number and decode as which protocol)